# Conditional Validation Rule in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a table in MS-Access - let's call it `tComputers`. Two of the fields in that table are titled `Status` - with the options of Active, Storage, Deactivated - and `DeactivationDate`.

If I wanted to make `DeactivationDate` mandatory if and only if the value of `Status` is Deactivated, how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If I wanted to make DeactivationDate mandatory if and only if the value of status is Deactivated how can I do that?*

Conversely, if a Deactivated record later changes Status ... say becomes Active ... should the DeactivationDate be discarded?

I think you can accomplish this with a table level Validation Rule.  With tComputers in Design View, open  the property sheet and use this as the Validation Rule property:

```
IsNull([DeactivationDate])=IIf([Status]="Deactivated",False,True)
```

Figure out what message you want the users to see when that validation rule is violated and put it in as the Validation Text property.  It's unlikely the default message would mean anything to them.

Although it's possible, I doubt know how useful this is.  The users should be editing data via a form, and that gives you the opportunity to enforce your validation requirements before the database 
engine even attempts to save the data ... use the Form_BeforeUpdate event as @mwolfe02 described.

**Edit**: Here is an outline for Form_BeforeUpdate.  It assumes you have a combo named cboStatus bound to the Status field, and a text box named txtRetireDate bound to the RetireDate field.

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim strMsg As String
    Select Case Me.cboStatus
    Case "Deactivated"
        If IsNull(Me.txtRetireDate) Then
            strMsg = "RetireDate is required for Status = Deactivated"
            MsgBox strMsg
            Me.txtRetireDate.SetFocus
            Cancel = True
        End If
    Case "Active", "Storage"
        '* what should happen here? *'
    Case Else
        '* what should happen here? *'
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: +1: For additional info, Allen Browne has a great primer on [Validation Rules](http://allenbrowne.com/ValidationRule.html).

Comment: Keep in mind that many valid Jet/ACE validation rules do not automatically upsize to SQL Server via any of the usual methods (e.g., SSMA for Access has problems with some pretty generic validation rules).

Comment: If I do use validation rules at the form level in the before update event as suggested - how do I cancel the save if it does not meet the validation requirements?

Comment: In the Form's Before Update event, set Cancel = True, as @mwolfe02 mentioned.  Alternatively, you can use Before Update events on individual controls to Cancel invalid updates immediately at each control before allowing the user to move on to another control.  In your case, I might also enable/disable the RequireDate control based on the value of the Status control ... assuming there is no point in allowing the user to input a RequireDate for Status other than Deactivated.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>If you want to enforce this at the table level I believe you are out of luck.  You might be able to do something with Data Macros if you are using Access 2010.</strike>  *EDIT: I stand corrected.  Though I personally don't ever use this functionality (preferring to handle the validation at the form level where more complex validation is practical) it is most definitely possible:  [Validation Rules](http://allenbrowne.com/ValidationRule.html)*

If your users will only be updating the data through a bound form, you can perform the validation in the `Form_BeforeUpdate` event.  Then if Status = 'Deactivated' and DeactivationDate is Null, you would set `Cancel = True` which will prevent the changes from being saved.  Obviously you'd want to show a message box or indicate in some other way why the form could not be saved.

Comment: Hi guys -- 

I had a tough time finding this in my searches in the last couple of hours until a friend of mine pointed me in the right direction. For the sake of reference if anyone comes across this page I'd like to post my answer as well.

The two answers are great options to enforce at the form level but here is how I enforced it at the table level:

In the table properties window there is a table validation rule field and I used this code:

***([Status] In ("Active","Storage","")) Or ([RetireDate] Is Not Null)***

Comment: @Zack: Nice work!  It's perfectly acceptable (even encouraged) to post an answer to your own question here on StackOverflow.  This is a perfect example of when that would be appropriate.  Future users are more likely to find your answer if it's not buried in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are entering the data with a form, you could use VBA to validate the form entries.  On the button press to save the data you can check to see if the value of status is Deactivated, and if it is, you can require DeactivationDate to have a value.  Otherwise, the data won't be saved.

Doing what you want in the table design window, I'm not sure how that could be done.