# How would I implement a required checkbox in MSAccess?

Tags: vba, ms-access

My problem is thus:

I'm designing a PPM Database, and want to set up a sort of validation rule that requires that, if the user filling the information in hasn't checked the box to say the maintenance work has been completed and carried out, they are required to choose one of the "Reason" drop down choices to explain why the work hasn't been done.

I've been doing some reading and it seems the best way to do this is through VBA. Unfortunately, my experience with VBA is very limited as most of my coding experience is in Java or C#.

What i'm looking for isn't simply a "Required Field" Checkbox, I have several of those set up for the form already, for example on the "Title" field or the "Type of PPM" field. I need a conditional required field function that will only be active if another field hasn't been checked off as "true".

Thank you in advance!

P.S.
I wrote out a rough bit of code to test, with regards to the logic I need.
If it's completely wrong i'm sorry, but like I said i have pretty much no experience with VBA. I just need a solution to this problem.

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel as Integer)
    If Me!Completed = True Then
        If IsNull(Me!Reason) Then
        MsgBox "If not completed, Reason must be provided", vbOKOnly
        Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the code your are working with? What part of your code doesn't work? We will not provide you code if you don't show any effort. Please read> [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Added the rough bit of code i wrote. I just really need to understand how i'd actually write the logic for the If statement in VBA.

Comment: Your `Form_BeforeUpdate` code looks ok. Does it work? (If no, how exactly?)

Comment: At the moment it tells me it can't compile properly because the sub or function isn't defined. I don't know if you have to import the form itself into vba but i can't find out how.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a **bound form**, implement the check in the `BeforeUpdate` event of the form. Here is an example:
[Conditional Validation Rule in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073549/conditional-validation-rule-in-ms-access)

If you use an **unbound form**, just run the check(s) before saving the record.